# Mocking $q.all in jasmine for angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I am writing jasmine test cases for an angular controller which have an init function having an array of promises to be resolved:

```
    (function () {
    angular.controller("xyz", ['$scope', "Utility", "Api",
        function ($scope, Utility, Api) {
            var locals = $scope.locals = {
                id: 1,
                amount: 2,
                products: 3
            };
            function init() {
                locals.busyPromise = Utility.resolveAll(
                    {
                        name: 'a',
                        promise: Api.get,
                        then: function (response) { locals.id = 2; }
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'b',
                        promise: Api.find,
                        then: function (response) { locals.amount = 4; }
                    }
                ).then(function (response) { locals.products = 6; });
            }
           init();
        }
    ])
})();
```

Utility is an external script which resolves each promise in the array and executes their then function to set local properties. Once all the promises in the array are resolved, it moves to then function of resolveAll and execute it.

My question is, how can we mock Utility.resolveAll while injecting dependencies in Jasmine. In my case, whatever I tried, it never enters the then block of individual promises and goes directly to then block of resolveAll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here what I would do:

First if all, mock `Utility` and `Api` services

```
  let Utility, Api;
  beforeEach(() => {
    Utility = jasmine.createSpyObj('Utility', ['resolveAll']);
    Api = jasmine.createSpyObj('Api', ['find', 'get']);
  });
```

Then in tests:

```
it('should test component startup', function() {
       let resolveObjects;

       Utility.resolveAll.and.callFake(function(...args) {
         resolveObjects = args; // save all arguments, passed to `resolveAll` method

         return $q.when();
       })

       $scope = $rootScope.$new();
       let controller = $controller('xyz', {$scope, Utility, Api});
       $rootScope.digest(); // resolve $q.when so you can test overall promise

       expect($scope.locals.products).toBe(6); // test overall promise

       // now, test all the arguments

       // 0
       expect(resolveObjects[0].name).toBe('a');

       resolveObjects[0].promise();
       expect(Api.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

       resolveObjects[0].then();
       expect($scope.locals.id).toBe(4); 

       // 1
       expect(resolveObjects[1.name).toBe('b');

       resolveObjects[1].promise();
       expect(Api.find).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

       resolveObjects[1].then();
       expect($scope.locals.products).toBe(4); 
});
```